# Dynamic ConditionBuilder

Tags: go, amazon-dynamodb

My problem is pretty simple, I would like to dynamically create filters to use it in my query input.
I must precise that the tf variable can't change.

So here is what I did :

```
totalFilter := expression.ConditionBuilder{}
filter := expression.Name("status").Equal(expression.Value("0"))
filter2 := expression.Name("foo").Equal(expression.Value("bar"))
filter3 := expression.Name("yes").Equal(expression.Value("no"))
tf := []expression.ConditionBuilder{filter, filter2, filter3}
for _, v := range tf {
    totalFilter = totalFilter.And(v)
}
expr := expression.NewBuilder().WithFilter(totalFilter)
builder, err := expr.Build()
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
    return err
}
```

But the probleme is that totalFilter is an empty struct so it's mode variable is equal to 0 and then it raise an alert because mode 0 is unsetCond.

The only workaround that I found is to do this :

```
for i, v := range tf {
    if i == 0 {
        totalFilter = v
    } else {
        totalFilter.And(v)
    }
}
```

But I was wondering if there is another solution.

Comment: Had the same problem, and did the same solution. Its working well for me so far. Golang promotes simplicity so I think simple solution is the best one.

Comment: Difficult to answer without seeing the complete code... What is `expression`? If so, add the relevant code. Your own package? A third-party package? If so, specify which one.

Comment: expression is a package from the dynamodb library. It’s doesn’t need more explanation.

Comment: @Kiki The provenance of the `expression` package can only be deduced from the `amazon-dynamodb` tag, not from the body of the question.

Comment: @Kiki Does my answer help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could abstract away the treatment of the first `expression.ConditionBuilder` in a custom variadic function taking at least one `expression.ConditionBuilder` parameter:

```
func And(first expression.ConditionBuilder, rest ...expression.ConditionBuilder) expression.ConditionBuilder {
    result := first
    for _, cb := range rest {
        result = result.And(cb)
    }
    return result
}
```

Then, in `main`:

```
filter := expression.Name("status").Equal(expression.Value("0"))
filter2 := expression.Name("foo").Equal(expression.Value("bar"))
filter3 := expression.Name("yes").Equal(expression.Value("no"))
totalFilter := And(filter, filter2, filter3)
expr := expression.NewBuilder().WithFilter(totalFilter)
builder, err := expr.Build()
// etc.
```

Note that a [similar function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/dynamodb/expression/#And), also named `And`, is exported by the `expression` package, but it takes at least two (not just one) `expression.ConditionBuilder` parameters. That's unfortunate...

Answer (score 0):

My approach was to create a "dummy" condition that will always return true, much like the `WHERE 1=1 [AND ...]` condition that is common in dynamic SQL statements.

The example code would become:

```golang
// dummy condition (1=1) to initialize the filter
totalFilter := expression.Equal(expression.Value(1), expression.Value(1))

filter := expression.Name("status").Equal(expression.Value("0"))
filter2 := expression.Name("foo").Equal(expression.Value("bar"))
filter3 := expression.Name("yes").Equal(expression.Value("no"))
tf := []expression.ConditionBuilder{filter, filter2, filter3}
for _, v := range tf {
    totalFilter = totalFilter.And(v)
}
expr := expression.NewBuilder().WithFilter(totalFilter)
builder, err := expr.Build()
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
    return err
}
```

**Note that if your other conditions are joined by an `OR` operation, the dummy condition would need to be inverted so that it always returns false.**